# How do the melting of any solid and Fermi Surface correlate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory

I was studying Electronic Bands in Solids and I came across this paragraph.

> "At absolute zero, this surface(Fermi Surface) encloses all the
> occupied sites. At other temperatures, however, there will be some
> unoccupied states within the Fermi surface, and some occupied states
> outside it. So at temperature T$\neq 0$ it is not so sharply defined
> as it is so at $T=0$.

Now I know meaning of this statement and Fermi Surface but next comes this statement

> Incidently, all the temperatures which the metals can sustain before
> they melt are small compared to the Fermi temperature so that region of
> partly occupied and partly unoccupied state will be quite thin and the
> essential features of the fermi surface picture will be unimpaired
> even at theses temperatures."

I am unable to understand this statement. Please elaborate it.